# Make TextBox border red when value is empty by using databinding in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, mvvm-light

I can make a TextBox red when the value is empty, but only after I click on a button. But how can I make it red when it is empty without clicking on a button?

I am using MVVM Light, it has somthing to do with "TwoWay"? Or RaisePropertyChanged or OnpropertyChanged?

This is a TextBox in my xaml:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 Width="200"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Background="Grey"
                 Foreground="White"
                 BorderThickness="1"
                 BorderBrush="{Binding Color, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

This is the code on my ViewModel:

```
 private SolidColorBrush _Color;
    public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get
        {
            return _Color;
        }
        set
        {
            _Color = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }
```

Then this is the button command:

```
 public RelayCommand UpdatePerson
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(async () =>
            {
                Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                //....      
            });
        }
    }
```

So what I want is that when the FirstName TextBox is empty the border becomes red, this without clicking on a button.

```
 private Person _SelectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedPerson = value;
            if (value.FirstName == "")
            {
                Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can change  `Color` at `SelectedPerson.FirstName` property setter

Comment: @Alexander I tried that but didn't worked.

Comment: it should work. Can you show your code? Actually it isn't good way to implement data validation. WPF has several features for this e.g.  [ValidationRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ExceptionValidationRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.exceptionvalidationrule%28v=vs.110%29.asp)

Comment: @Alexander Added the piece of code at the end. And this is not wpf but a windows universal app.

Comment: As @Robert say you need move `Color` changing to `SelectedPerson.FirstName` setter (not `SelectedPerson`)

Answer (score 5):

if you simply want to red all those field which not contain any value you can use this

```
<Style.Triggers>
 <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>
 </Trigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `Color` from the `SelectedPerson.FirstName` setter and make sure you set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` in the binding for the `Text` property.

---

**Edit 1**

In response to your comment I would suggest that you implement a `FirstName` property in your ViewModel like this:

```
public String FirstName
{
    get { return SelectedPerson.FirstName; }
    set
    {
        SelectedPerson.FirstName = value;
        // Update 'Color' here
    }
}
```

And then in the View the binding for the `Text` property would look something like this:

```
{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

instead of

```
{Binding SelectedPerson.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Comment: I don't have a SelectedPerson.Firstname setter becouse this is a part of SelectedPerson.